# Number of regular polygons which satisfy two given conditions

Tags: geometry

> Find the number of values of $n$ for which the $n$-sided regular polygon satisfies the following two conditions:
>
> 1) the exterior angle is greater than $24°$;
>
> 2) the number of diagonals is greater than $20$.

(original question in spanish: ¿Cuantos números de polígonos regulares que existen tal que la medida del angulo exterior es un valor mayor que 24° y el numero de diagonales es mayor que 20?)

My approach:

$$360/n > 24 → 15 > n$$

$$(n(n-3))/2 > 20 → n>-8 ; n>5 ; n<-8; n<5$$

Then I graphed it on a number line and it did not come out. Is this how it is done?

(Original: Luego lo grafique en una recta númerica y no me salio
¿Así se hace? ...)

Comment: Writing in English makes your question available for a much wider range of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first condition you are correct: we have that
$$\frac{360}{n} > 24 \implies 15 > n.$$
As regards the second one, you are right again, it says that
$$\frac{n(n-3)}{2}>20.$$
Now note that $n$  is a **positive integer** ($n$ is the number of sides of a polygon) and $n\to \frac{n(n-3)}{2}$ is strictly increasing for $n\geq 3$. Moreover for $n=8$, $\frac{8(8-3)}{2}=20$. What may we conclude?

P.S. By the way, in your work, instead of $-8$ and $5$ you should have $8$ and $-5$.

Comment: Gracias, solo el numero 8 cumple con la condición

Comment: Yes, for $n=8$ you have the equality but you need that $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}>20$. Then?

Comment: ¿Se puede hacer también con gráficos, es decir primero resolviendo las inecuaciones y luego graficandolas en la recta y que la salgo solo el número 8 ... o solo remplazando los valores? 4,5,6,7,8,9, .. .15 ,? por que yo solo remplace ...

Comment: Why don't you solve $\frac{n(n-3)}{2}>20$ that is $n^2-3n-40=(n+5)(n-8)>0$?

Comment: Muchas gracias, Me salio que 6 son los polígonos que cumplen con esa condición.

Comment: @Strong Yes, you are correct.